# EDIT-UPDATE BUTTONS IN Repeater control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a repeater control with collapsible panel inside a div.(class header and class detail).when i click Edit button inside the detail division - cancel and update button are showing but when i click the edit button the div is collapsing and can see the update and cancel button only after clicking the row one more time..

Every thing is working fine except below stated one.
**Each time i click edit button division is collapsing
How can  i make the class detail stable until i do edit/cancel/update.**

Thanks

```
 <style>
.header { font-size: larger; font-weight: bold; cursor: hand; cursor:pointer;
       background-color:#cccccc; font-family: Verdana; }
.details { display:none; visibility:hidden; 
         font-family: Verdana; }
</style>

&nbsp;<div style="overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;background-  color:gray;     height: 500px; width: 895px">

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

      <ItemTemplate>


 <div id='h<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="header"
   onclick='ToggleDisplay(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>);' style="border-style: none;">
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="30px" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="#79FFFF">

<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "License")%> 
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>

<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem," Date")%>
```

```
 <div id='d<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="details">

 <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="195px" BackColor="Gray" Font-Bold="False"   ForeColor="Maroon">
 <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="LicenseID"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval  (Container.DataItem,"LicenseID") %>' Enabled="False" BackColor="Gray"   BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="License  Name"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LicenseName")%>' Enabled="false" BackColor="Gray" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>

         </asp:Panel>

 </div>

      </ItemTemplate>
```

Toggle display

```
        function ToggleDisplay(id) {
       var elem = document.getElementById('d' + id);
       if (elem) {
            if (elem.style.display != 'block') {
            elem.style.display = 'block';
            elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else {
            elem.style.display = 'none';
            elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You have some unclosed tags there. Double check it.

Comment: For each click of edit button inside the detail panel will make the detail division collapse.Then when i click again will expand and show update/save link.This is my issue

Comment: You didn't get my point. You have a `<asp:Panel>` unclosed tag.

Comment: And can you show the code for the `ToggleDisplay` function?

Comment: sorry that happened while i copy/paste the code.

Comment: You don't need to set both `display` and `visibility`. One or the other is enough. I would leave just the `display`.

Comment: Also, this bit `var elem = document.getElementById('d' + id);` should be `var elem = document.getElementById('h' + id);`.

Comment: Actually, it won't work at all. You can't click something that's not displayed and make it visible. You would need to work the toggle on children elements. Or your code posted (HTML) is incomplete or it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Melancia ,i have posted full code.Thanks